# Research - What is the best way to name a study?

Tags: user-research

I am planning my first usability study and I want to hear some thoughts on what is the best practice for naming a usability study - for external purposes.

For screening for recruitment, I will need to mention the name of the survey. But I do not wish to give away the platform or product we are targeting, so that users don't get biased. How would one normally name a study for external users?

+I'm working on a benchmark test, if this helps anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call it what is is and use generic platform labels**

Either call it a 'usability study', or, if appropriate, the more meaningful 'website/app evaluation'.

Use the broadest generic terms to describe your platform. Facebook > social media, Instagram > photo sharing, Linkedin > professional networking, etc.

e.g. Photo-sharing app evaluation.